# windows VPS running apache and mysql, php scripts running slow.. but cpu usage is 1-3%

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2003, mysql, vps

So every night I run some cron jobs.  It requires probably about 20 min to process all the records.  I gather the script does something like 10,000 sql queries.

I figure this task was just that intense and needs time to complete, but I looked at CPU and memory usage, and it is super low.  Cpu usage is between 1-3% and once in a while will bounce to 50ish for 2-3 seconds.

This VPS is running windows 2003 server with Apache and MySQL.  Does this sound right?

Answer (score 0):

How much **RAM** do you have on the machine? If it is too little, it could be choking and trashing the swap. That can explain the slow speeds on low-cpu usage.

Comment: 512 mb right now.  showing 134,492 available while running.

Comment: 512 sounds a bit limited with what you have running. Have you tried tuning Apache + MySQL to run with less memory? Particularly for MySQL.

Comment: nope I have not.  I just assumed cpu useage would be higher.  maybe apache automatically throttles cpu to make sure it could handle other requests and such..

Comment: Just to test, why don't you try reducing the number of Apache worker threads/listening processes to a minimum and also to reduce the amount of memory used by MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you know everything the scripts are doing?  Maybe the process is disk bound.  Some Linux machines run `makewhatis` every night and update the database used by `locate`.  To do so, they scan the entire disk compiling a list of filenames.  There's a lot of I/O but not much CPU usage.  Maybe Windows does something similar?  Compiling statistics by parsing the web logs?

If you really are doing lots of SQL queries, maybe they're running on non-indexed fields of large tables, and MySQL has to scan through a lot of records.  I think you need to take a closer look at what the nightly process does, in order to track down why it takes so long.